# Can I Use Regex In ElasticSearch with Java?

Tags: java, regex, search, elasticsearch, filtering

I am new at ElasticSearch , I read elasticsearch java-api guide and I learned lot of things indexing geting searching filtering , However I think elasticsearch guide isn't enough to learn details. I want to understand every filtering,query details. Examples are very poor.If Anyone knows elasticsearch java examples document share please.And Can I use regex in ElasticSearch with Java  ? I didn't find any example in google.

```
  Elastic Search Example :
   {
"regexp":{
    "name.first": "s.*y"
}
```

}

```
 {
"regexp":{
    "name.first": "s.*y",
    "flags" : "INTERSECTION|COMPLEMENT|EMPTY"
}
```

}

How can I adapt these codes to Java ? There aren't any examples in guide and google .

Answer (score 1):

I like to read source if the doco isn't helping.

[You can find the ES source here](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch).

[Here is one of their tests that uses Java and parses regexpQuery](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/464037e0c18d5bbcc33db0e01acde6c8849324a9/src/test/java/org/elasticsearch/index/query/SimpleIndexQueryParserTests.java#L595)

```
public void testRegexpQueryBuilder() throws IOException {
        IndexQueryParserService queryParser = queryParser();
        Query parsedQuery = queryParser.parse(regexpQuery("name.first", "s.*y")).query();
        assertThat(parsedQuery, instanceOf(RegexpQuery.class));
        RegexpQuery regexpQuery = (RegexpQuery) parsedQuery;
        assertThat(regexpQuery.getField(), equalTo("name.first"));
    }
```

Comment: I want to learn use this method with searching.Help me please

Answer (score 0):

I found , if anyone needs this is the best method for searching with regexp ( ElasticSearch Java-api );

```
  SearchResponse r = client.prepareSearch("Face".toLowerCase())
                    .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
                    .setQuery(spanOrQuery().clause(spanMultiTermQueryBuilder(regexpQuery("Message", "fener"))) )
                    .setFrom(0).setSize(60).setExplain(true)
                    .execute()
                    .actionGet();
```